# QGIS plugin 'Module' object has no attribute 'classFactory'

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, qt-designer

I am trying to learn how to make QGIS plugins and have been trying to follow tutorials such as this one;
    https://anitagraser.com/2014/04/26/getting-started-writing-qgis-2-x-plugins/
    but I keep getting this error right in the first few steps

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 306, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'classFactory'
```

I did not change any code in the utilis.py so I am wondering if anyone knows what might be the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Same problem cant find an answer anywhere.